# How do I best apply async await to a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am a relative noop at C# and his is my first attempt at asynchronous methods.  I've put together a simple practice app (WPF MVVM) that lists the performance counters on my system.  I've spent a few hours at this point reading questions and posts found via google.  According to several of them, I am doing this wrong, but I made several attempts at making the below code work better.  Admittedly, I am a bit confused by a lot of the documentation and help guides, on distinguishing between async and Tasks. [This guide](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) has offered a bit of help but I'm struggling to apply it to my code.

**The Code**

```
public async void UpdateCounters(PerformanceCounterCategory category)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Counters = GetCounters(category);
        });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter> GetCounters(PerformanceCounterCategory category)
    {
        var countersList = new ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>();
        if(category != null)
        {
            var instances = category.GetInstanceNames().OrderBy(ins => ins);
            if(instances.Any())
            {
                foreach(var instance in instances)
                {
                    if(category.InstanceExists(instance))
                    {
                        //this is time consuming segment when I'm listing something like "Process" counters
                        var counters = category.GetCounters(instance);
                        foreach(var counter in counters)
                            countersList.Add(counter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return countersList;
    }
```

I've tried converting the method to an async method.  Like so...

```
private async Task<List<PerformanceCounter>> GetCounters(PerformanceCounterCategory category)
        {   //Changes receiving expression to Counter = new ObservableCollection(GetCounters(category));
            var countersList = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
//But I couldn't figure out where to put the await
```

I'm ultimately wanting to display "waiting..." or some other prompt/progress indicator on the UI, but I want to do it the right way.  My current codes prevents it from being non-responsive, but that's about all.

Should this all be in a single async method, possibly like I've already done with a bit better coding, or should I be creating a list of tasks in the foreach.  (I took at shot that too but it was an epic failure).

Comment: @lumberajackshaw read this link as well and understand what `Design-Pattern` that @PranayRana has used it will help you later in case you run across different patterns in Code / Design [.NET Design Patterns](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/dotnet/1092/dotnet-design-patterns)

Comment: updated my answer with exception handling ...for each individual task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do as below

```
private async Task<List<PerformanceCounter>> GetCounters(PerformanceCounterCategory category)
{   
  List<Task<PerformanceCounter>> lstTask = new     
                     List<Task<PerformanceCounter>>();
  List<PerformanceCounter> counters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();

  //your code 
 foreach(var instance in instances)
 {
   lstTask.Add( Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> return    
  category.GetCounters(instance)));
 }

  try {
     await Task.WhenAll(lstTask.ToArray());
  }
  catch {}  
  foreach(var task in lstTask )
  {
    if(task.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted)
       counters.Add(task.Result);
    else 
        //log error task.Exception
  }

   return counters ;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have  is the try/catch with the `t.Wait()`? also `t` is a `Task[]` not a `Task`,

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - thanks ..i just typing her without trying but its updated now ..just need to put try..catch around await taks ...updated sma e..thanks for pointing my mistake

Comment: @PranayRana, I'm having a bit of trouble with lstTask.Add( Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> return  category.GetCounters(instance)));
I took out the return, but then end up with  issues converting a ...PerformanceCounter[] to ...PerformanceCounter.

Comment: @PranayRana, I think I got it after changing lstTask to List<Task<PerformanceCounter[]>>.

Comment: @lumberajackshaw - ok , dont forget to upvote/accept if it worked for you..